# Sending Email on behalf of your client

Tags: email, dns

Basically when you send an email with a different sending domain from the FROM email. It will probably end up in spam. I know a little about DKIM especially for domain you own. My question this: how does email service providers like mailchimp, aweber and the rest send email on our behalf (even for free domain like gmail.com, yahoo.com) without ending up in junk.

Can someone show me the steps involved in sending email on behalf of your clients  with different email address (like email service providers)?

Do you need to automatically signed all the email with DKIM or something